# why is Hover not working with list nested under another list

Tags: html, css, hover

I am running this simple "test" code to change the background color of the nested list`<ul class="dropcontent">`  by using :hover on parent `<li class="drop">`

```css
.drop:hover .dropcontent {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="drop"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <ul class="dropcontent">
      <li><a href="#">serv1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">serv2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">serv3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">serv4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">serv5</a></li>
    </ul>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Get in Touch</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Please someone explain what's wrong here.

Comment: it's not nested, it's sibling and invalid as html

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks for the comment. Can you please help me with this? It's displaying fine just like a nested list. the problem is, hover doesn't work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.dropcontent` is a sibling of `.drop` (not a descendant), so the selector `.drop:hover .dropcontent` will not target it.

To correct this, either move the closing `</li>` of `.drop` to after the closing `</ul>` of `.dropcontent`:

```css
.drop:hover .dropcontent {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="drop"><a href="#">Services</a>
      <ul class="dropcontent">
        <li><a href="#">serv1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">serv2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">serv3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">serv4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">serv5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Get in Touch</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Or make use of the [adjacent sibling combinator (`+`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) with the selector `.drop:hover + .dropcontent`:

```css
.drop:hover + .dropcontent {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="drop"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <ul class="dropcontent">
      <li><a href="#">serv1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">serv2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">serv3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">serv4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">serv5</a></li>
    </ul>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Get in Touch</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Note that the former will apply the hover while the child links are selected, while the latter will only apply the hover when `.drop` itself is selected.